# VueJS - SSR - Wait for async data in created() hook before render

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, lifecycle

I have a VueJS microfrontend that is SSR thanks to a Ara Framework cluster.
In order to make it fully autonomous I would like it to fetch data in the created() hook before the render occurs so that I have a fully complete DOM rendered in SSR.

Logging showed the problem is created() does not wait for my axios data call to end wheter I use async/await, then() or a classic Promise. Then it either fails on DOM or renders a empty dom if I add a v-if="data"

The idea would be to have a functionnal asyncData() like in Nuxt without to have using the whole framework as I have Ara Framework already applying SSR to my Vue app.

```
 created() {
return new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log('created')
  const { interfaceIn, InterfaceEnum } = this.interfaceService
  console.log('1')

  if (this.hydratation) {
    this.article = interfaceIn(InterfaceEnum.ARTICLE, this.hydratation)
  } else {
    console.log('1,5')
    this.utils.api
      .mainGet(
        axios,
        this.$utils.api.getHostByContext('ctx1', 'ctx2'),
        `/news/${this.slug}`,
        'Article'
      )
      .then(data => {
        console.log('2')

        this.article = interfaceIn(InterfaceEnum.ARTICLE, data.article)
        console.log('3')
        resolve()
      })
    console.log('4')

    // this.article = interfaceIn(InterfaceEnum.ARTICLE, article)
    console.log(this.article.id)
  }
})
// this.loading = false
// this.loading = true
```

}

[console output on SSR http call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdvNM.png)

[HTTP call used with ara Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDmf1.png)

Minimal repro is quite complex to provide as it requires the microfrontend + working ara framework cluster for SSR

Thanks

Comment: How do you resolve the promise if the else condition isn't triggered or there is an error?

Answer (score 2):

Answer was to use the serverPrefetch() lifeCycle hook designed for this.

Comment: were you using vue2 or vue3? If vue3 how did you wait for `rendered` before proceeding?

Comment: Just note that `serverPrefetch` is VUE native (you do not need Nuxt) and is also available in VUE 2 and 3.